# Automatically updating a MySQL database when a new csv file is saved inside a folder

Tags: mysql, vb.net, csv

I am trying to create some sort of an event or script that detects when a new csv is saved into a folder, and then inserts the content of this csv folder inside a MySQL server.

Is this possible? If it is how can I approach this problem and what materials should I study to make this happen?

I am using .net to create applications right now and created a csv importer using `OpenFileDialog()` However my boss wants me automatically scrape a csv whenever a new file is saved.

Comment: Take a look at the FileSystemWatcher https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is helpful, thank you